# SSRS Expression Sum Between Numbers

Tags: sql, vb.net, expression, reporting-services

I am seeking assistance with creating a VB expression in SSRS that subtracts SUMS.  I have a dataset that has accounts and corresponding money/amount values.  I need help creating an expression that sums up the money/amount values from one group of the accounts in a specified range, and then subtracts it from the money/amount total of another range.  Specifically:

```
(Sum(amt) where acct between 40000 and 49999) -
(Sum(amt) where (acct between 50000 and 59999) or (acct between 66000 and 69999)) -
(Sum(amt) where acct between 76000 and 79825) -
(Sum(amt) where acct between 89000 and 90399)
```

Really need help translating this SQL logic into a VB expression to be used for a textbox in SSRS.  Any advice would be extremely helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

textbox can only capture the first value of the dataset, so if you go to the expression builder for the textbox, you can see there are no fields from the dataset available. But, aggregate functions on dataset fields are available.

So you can create a calculated field to your dataset and add amount values to it with appropriate signs such that the sum of all the values in this calculated field represents your desired solution.

For example, add a new calculated field to your dataset. In the field source, add an appropriate expression like:

```
=IIF(Fields!acct.Value>=40000 AND Fields!acct.Value<=49999, CInt(Fields!amt.Value),
   IIF(   (Fields!acct.Value>=50000 AND Fields!acct.Value<=59999)  OR
          (Fields!acct.Value>=66000 AND Fields!acct.Value<=69999)  OR
          (Fields!acct.Value>=76000 AND Fields!acct.Value<=79825)  OR
          (Fields!acct.Value>=89000 AND Fields!acct.Value<=90399), 
                 CInt(0 - Fields!amt.Value), CInt(0)
      )
    )
```

This keeps the values between 40000 and 49999 as they are. Makes all values needed to be subtracted into negative values. And everything else you don't wish to consider as 0.

Therefore when you call

```
Sum(Fields!calcfield.Value, "your dataset name")
```

from the textbox, you add the values between 40000 and 49999, and subtract values in ranges you wanted.

Please change the expression for the calculated field as per your need, the procedure will work.
You shouldn't go through all the values in a dataset directly from a textbox.

Hope it helps.